# How to call the function of UIViewController in a subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I create a subclass of `UILabel` called `NewLabel`, in `NewLabel.m`, codes like this

```
+ (NewLabel*)addLabelIntoView:(UIView*)view
{
  NewLabel *label = [[NewLabel alloc] init];
  //some codes
  [view addSubview:label];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:view selector:@selector(callActionInVC) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
  return label;
}
```

and there's a `UIViewController`, codes in `UIViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [NewLabel addLabelIntoView:self.view]
}

- (void)callActionInVC {
    //do some actions
}
```

I want to call the function `callActionInVC` of `UIViewController.m` in `NewLabel.m`, and in `NewLabel.m`, `target:view` is not right, What should I change to? What's the target of a UIViewController in a subclass?

Or is there any ideas to make this demand?

Comment: use delegate pattern

Comment: set `target: <Your ViewController> selector:@selector(<YourViewController.method>)`

Comment: @MahendraGP thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `target` is wrong

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:view selector:@selector(callActionInVC) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

You should set target as the controller.

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:<your controller> selector:@selector(callActionInVC) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

You may need to create a [category](https://github.com/TongFangyuan/WorkSummary/blob/master/FYCategoryExample/FYCategory/UIView/UIView%2BFYController.m) to get the controller.

```
- (UIViewController *)fy_parentController{
    UIResponder *responder = [self nextResponder];
    while (responder) {

        if ([responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            return (UIViewController *)responder;
        }
        responder = [responder nextResponder];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The final code looks like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:view.fy_parentController selector:@selector(callActionInVC) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.